# Is there a closed formula for the integral

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

I want to calculate the following integral ($a>0$):
$$
\int_0^1\dfrac{1-e^{-at}}{at}\,dt=\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n(at)^n}{(n+1)!}\,dt\,=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^na^n}{(n+1)(n+1)!}
$$

I'd like to know if the last series has a closed formula. Any other way of calculation is also welcome.

Comment: It has a formula in terms of the exponential integral function. Is that closed enough? Actually there's even a function that is specifically the integral $\int_0^z [1-\exp(-t)]/t dt$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Which special function is this?

Comment: It's called [Exponential Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\Re(a)>0$

$$\int\limits_0^1\frac{1-e^{-a t}}{a t}\,dt=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n a^n}{(n+1) (n+1)!}$$ $$=\frac{-\text{Ei}(-a)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\log(-a)-\log\left(-\frac{1}{a}\right)\right)+\gamma}{a}$$ $$=\frac{\Gamma(0,a)+\log(a)+\gamma}{a}=\frac{E_1(a)+\log(a)+\gamma}{a}\tag{1}$$

and for $a>0$

$$\frac{-\text{Ei}(-a)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\log(-a)-\log\left(-\frac{1}{a}\right)\right)+\gamma}{a}=\frac{-\text{Ei}(-a)+\log(a)+\gamma }{a}.\tag{2}$$

---

The $\Gamma(0,z)$, $E_1(z)$, and $\text{Ei}(z)$ functions are related as follows

$$\Gamma(0,z)=E_1(z)=-\text{Ei}(-z)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\log(-z)-\log\left(-\frac{1}{z}\right)\right)-\log(z)\tag{3}$$

which for a real argument simplifies to:

$$\Gamma(0,x)=E_1(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 -\text{Ei}(-x)-i \pi  & x<0 \\
 -\text{Ei}(-x) & x>0 \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{4}$$

---

You can find a number of representations of the $\text{Ei}(z)$ function [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/ExpIntegralEi/), incomplete gamma function $\Gamma(a,z)$ [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma2/), and exponential integral function $E_n(z)$ [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/ExpIntegralE/).

---

Wikipedia uses the related entire function (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Definition_by_Ein))

$$E_{in}(z)=\int\limits_0^z \frac{1-e^{-t}}{t}\,dt=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k\, k!} z^k=\gamma+\log(z)+\Gamma (0,z)\tag{5}$$

to define $E_1(z)$ as

$$E_1(z)=-\log (z)-\gamma+E_{in}(z),\quad |\arg(z)|<\pi\tag{6}$$

and $\text{Ei}(x)$ as

$$\text{Ei}(x)=\gamma+\log(|x|)-E_{in}(-x),\quad x\neq 0\ .\tag{7}$$

---

Therefore

$$\int\limits_0^z \frac{1-e^{-a t}}{a t}\,dt=\frac{E_{in}(a z)}{a}\tag{8}$$

and

$$\int\limits_0^1 \frac{1-e^{-a t}}{a t}\,dt=\frac{E_{in}(a)}{a}.\tag{9}$$

---

Here's a more unusual formula for $E_1(z)$ (and $\Gamma(0,z)$) where the evaluation limits $N$ and $f$ are both assumed to be positive integers. Formula (10) below is valid for $\Re(z)>0$.

$$E_1(z)=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \mu(2 n-1) \left(\frac{1}{2 (2 n-1) z}+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2 f\, (2 n-1)} \frac{(-1)^k \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi k}{(2 n-1) z}\right)}{k}\right)\right)\tag{10}$$

---

Figures (1) to (3) below illustrate the evaluation of formula (10) for $E_1(z)$ in orange overlaid on the blue reference function where formula (10) is evaluated at $N=20$ and $f=4$ for all three figures.

---

[image: Illustration of formula (10)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of formula (10) for $E_1(z)$ evaluated for $z>0$

---

[image: Illustration of real part of formula (10)]

**Figure (2)**: Illustration of real part of formula (10) for $E_1(z)$ evaluated along the line $z=\frac{1}{2}+i\,t$

---

[image: Illustration of imaginary part of formula (10)]

**Figure (3)**: Illustration of imaginary part of formula (10) for $E_1(z)$ evaluated along the line $z=\frac{1}{2}+i\,t$

---

Formula (10) above can also be modified to evaluate $\text{Ei}(-z)$ for $\Re(z)>0$ as follows where the $-i\, \pi\, \text{sgn}(\Im(z))$ term accounts for the branch cut of the $\text{Ei}(z)$ function along the negative real axis.

$$\text{Ei}(-z)=-i\, \pi\, \text{sgn}(\Im(z))-\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \mu(2 n-1) \left(\frac{1}{2 (2 n-1) z}+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2 f\, (2 n-1)} \frac{(-1)^k \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi k}{(2 n-1) z}\right)}{k}\right)\right)\tag{11}$$

---

Figures (4) to (6) below illustrate the evaluation of formula (11) for $\text{Ei}(-z)$ in orange overlaid on the blue reference function where formula (11) is evaluated at $N=20$ and $f=4$ for all three figures.

---

[image: Illustration of formula (11)]

**Figure (4)**: Illustration of formula (11) for $\text{Ei}(-z)$ evaluated for $z>0$

---

[image: Illustration of real part of formula (11)]

**Figure (5)**: Illustration of real part of formula (11) for $\text{Ei}(-z)$ evaluated along the line $z=\frac{1}{2}+i\,t$

---

[image: Illustration of imaginary part of formula (11)]

**Figure (6)**: Illustration of imaginary part of formula (11) for $\text{Ei}(-z)$ evaluated along the line $z=\frac{1}{2}+i\,t$

---

Comment: @user103 I can give you more unusual series representation if you're still interested but it will take a bit more time.